# Unique Need - Perform Team Services releases using artifacts created in an external build

Tags: azure-devops

I have a unique need where I need to perform releases from Team Services using a Release Pipeline and artifacts that have been created in a previous external build. I have the artifacts that were created, dacpacs and websites ect.

I would like to deploy these items using the features in release Pipelines but artifact sources only come from a build or some other version control.

My approach (hack) was to use a build to copy the external files and publish them into the artifact container for the build. I could then use the release pipelines to do my releases. But .. Build copy tasks only seem to work with paths into a repo.

My fall back will be to use the release pipeline and powershell to do the releases with these externally created artifacts. I would sure like to avoid this since there is nice capability in the release pipeline tasks.

This is a compliance requirement my firm has which results in the rather crazy post.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Copy Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) task and [Publish Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts) task for your build definition.

#### Copy Files task

- **Source Folder:** you can specify the folder which has your external build artifacts. Such as `C:\project\a`.
- **Contents:** you can use wildcards to specify which files to copy. Such as `**\*.dll`, this will copy all `*.dll` files in `C:\project\a` and it’s subfilder.
- **Target Folder:** where you want to copy these files. Usually it’s `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

#### Publish Build Artifacts task

- **Path to Publish:** set as the same with Target folder in Copy files task. Such as `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

**Note:** Copy files task will find the source folder in the machine where the private agent is located.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work for me. I am using a private agent and the task is running on it. My external files are in (C:\Deployments\Release-14) on the private agent.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work for me. I am using a private agent and the task is running on it. My external files are in (C:\Deployments\Release-14) on the private agent. I put (C:\Deployments\Release-14) in source folder and (*.zip) in the contents. I get the error (2017-04-12T13:05:22.9348054Z ##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: C:\Deployments\Release-14) in the log. Any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: So your private agent is not deployed on this local machine? The task will find the source folder in the machine where the private agent is locate. So you can deploy another agent on this machine and have a try.

Comment: OK, I noticed that I was not running the build on the private agent, when I run it there i get this (Unhandled: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:\deployments\Release-14')

Comment: OK, just got it to work. There was something weird about the "deployments" folder. When i copied the files from another location it worked!! If you are ever in the phila area, look me up i owe you at least a beer